# How am I supposed to serve breakfast?

Tags: wallace-and-gromit-1

I am playing Wallace and Gromit Episode 1; Fright of the Bumblebees, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to serve Wallace his breakfast!

I tried to make toast, and a squirrel just ran off with it. I tried to make eggs, and the machine is broken. I have clicked all the things, and I have a stick of butter in my inventory, but it doesn't seem to help me at the moment.

Help! What can I do? Wallace is hungry, and he won't be happy until he gets something to eat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to hint you first, but there's a full walkthrough [here](http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcWw/WallaceGromit1.htm):

As far as the toast goes:

> The toast is nabbed by a squirrel, Nutter. He leaves paw print on an empty butter dish. Hmm.

The egg machine is considerably more complex a solution.  There is a "part" missing, so you may need to explore some other parts of the house to find another mechanism to steal it from.

Comment: If I had realized that was a butter dish, things would've gone a lot smoother. :)